# record live streaming audio

Tags: objective-c, streaming, ipad, core-audio, audio-recording

I'm actually making an app which has to play and record streaming audio from internet on ipad. The streaming of the audio is done, I will have to come to the recording part very soon and I don't have any idea on how to proceed.

Could you give me a hint??? Idea? It will have to play while simultaneously recording into AAC or MP3.

Thanks.

Comment: Any solution for this? Please find the following link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931615/how-to-record-livestream-audio-and-save-to-documents-directory-while-playing

Comment: Can you please provide me if you got any solution for recording liveStream audio?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the lower-level AudioQueue API, and use the AudioSession API to set up the audio session.

Then you'll need to fill out an `AudioStreamBasicDescription` struct and create a new input queue with `AudioQueueNewInput()` and include your callback function for handling input buffers.

And then you'll need to create 3 buffers using `AudioQueueAllocateBuffer()` and `AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer()`. And only then will you be ready to call `AudioQueueStart()`. You should also handle audio session interruptions, and handle stopping the audio queue.

That will just get you a stream of buffers containing uncompressed 16-bit integer PCM audio data. You still need to compress the data, which is another can of worms that involves using the `AudioConverter` API, which I haven't done on the iPhone OS so I don't know what will work there.

Comment: Hi lucius

Thanks, can you explain a little bit more xD I'm a new and i'm lost :s

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Do you have an example of code which does this i.e recording? :(

Answer (score 0):

Please Look at this Framework. It provide data for recording while recording [Streaming Kit](https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit)

Play an MP3 over HTTP

```
STKAudioPlayer* audioPlayer = [[STKAudioPlayer alloc] init];

[audioPlayer play:@"http://www.abstractpath.com/files/audiosamples/sample.mp3"];
```

And append its data to NSMutabledata to play offline by using this delegate.

Intercept PCM data just before its played

```
 [audioPlayer appendFrameFilterWithName:@"MyCustomFilter" block:^(UInt32 channelsPerFrame, UInt32 bytesPerFrame, UInt32 frameCount, void* frames)
   {
   ...
   }];
```